# Why is my event handler firing twice even after using stopPropagation and preventDefault in Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

My event handler is firing twice and I can't figure out why.

As you can see in my code below, I've tried stopPropagation (even though from what I've read that would has to do with other event listeners that I don't have in my code), preventDefault, and double checking that the event isn't listening to the other handlers ('if e.target.id !==') but the console.log still gives me two outputs each click.

Below is the javascript, the event handler that fires twice is just under the addPlayer function.

```js
const playerFactory = () => {
  const players = [];
  const makePlayer = (name, marker) => {
    return {
      name,
      marker,
    };
  };

  let activePlayer;
  const pname = document.getElementById("pname");
  const p1 = document.getElementById("playerOne");
  const p2 = document.getElementById("playerTwo");
  const submit = document.getElementById("psubmit");
  const p1name = document.getElementById("playerOne");
  const p2name = document.getElementById("playerTwo");

  const addPlayer = () => {
    if (players.length === 2) {
      submit.textContent = "Game's Full";
      return;
    } else if (players.length === 0) {
      submit.classList.remove("alert");
      players.push(makePlayer(pname.value, "X"));
    } else {
      players.push(makePlayer(pname.value, "O"));
      activePlayer = players[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
      if (activePlayer === players[0]) {
        p1.classList.add("alert");
      } else {
        p2.classList.add("alert");
      }
    }
  };

  submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.id !== "psubmit") return;
    addPlayer();
    if (players.length === 1) {
      p1name.textContent = `${players[0].name}`;
    } else if (players.length === 2) {
      p2name.textContent = `${players[1].name}`;
    }
    console.log(activePlayer);
  });

  let getPlayers = () => players;
  let getActive = () => activePlayer;

  let switchActive = () => {
    if (activePlayer === players[0]) {
      activePlayer = players[1];
      p2.classList.add("alert");
      p1.classList.remove("alert");
    } else {
      activePlayer = players[0];
      p1.classList.add("alert");
      p2.classList.remove("alert");
    }
  };

  return {
    addPlayer,
    getPlayers,
    getActive,
    switchActive
  };
};

function gameBoard() {
  const board = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    board[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      board[i].push(Cell());
    }
  }
  const getBoard = () => board;

  return {
    getBoard
  };
}

function Cell() {
  let mark = "stunna";
  const getMark = () => mark;
  const addMark = (player) => (mark = player.marker);
  const resetMark = () => (mark = "stunna");
  return {
    getMark,
    addMark,
    resetMark
  };
}

function gameState() {
  const players = playerFactory();
  const board = gameBoard();
  const submit = document.getElementById("psubmit");
  const p1 = document.getElementById("playerOne");
  const p2 = document.getElementById("playerTwo");
  const p1name = document.getElementById("playerOne");
  const p2name = document.getElementById("playerTwo");

  let xWins = 0;
  let oWins = 0;

  function displayBoard() {
    const display = document.getElementById("gameboard");
    let row = 0;
    board.getBoard().forEach((x) => {
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.classList.add("cell");
        button.setAttribute("data-row", `${row}`);
        button.setAttribute("data-column", `${i}`);
        display.appendChild(button);
        let attempts = 0;
        // placing your X or O
        button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          if (players.getPlayers().length < 2) {
            const submit = document.getElementById("psubmit");
            submit.classList.add("alert");
            return;
          } else if (
            board
            .getBoard()[Number(e.target.dataset.row)][
              Number(e.target.dataset.column)
            ].getMark() !== "stunna"
          ) {
            return;
          } else {
            if (players.getActive() === players.getPlayers()[0]) {
              e.target.textContent = "X";
            } else {
              e.target.textContent = "0";
            }
            board
              .getBoard()[Number(e.target.dataset.row)][
                Number(e.target.dataset.column)
              ].addMark(players.getActive());
            checkForWin();
          }
        });
      }
      row++;
    });
  }

  function eraseBoard() {
    const display = document.getElementById("gameboard");
    const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
    Array.from(cells).forEach((cell) => display.removeChild(cell));
    board.getBoard().forEach((row) => {
      row.forEach((cell) => cell.resetMark());
    });
  }

  const p1winner = document.getElementById("p1winner");
  const p2winner = document.getElementById("p2winner");
  const p1Wins = document.getElementById("Xwins");
  const p2Wins = document.getElementById("Owins");
  const popup = document.getElementById("newGame");

  //takes winning player and adds to their total win count, makes pop-up appear
  function gameOverMan(player) {
    let winningMsgs = [
      "astonishes with their magnificent ",
      "perserveres aided by their crafty ",
      "dominates leading the big big ",
    ];
    if (player === players.getPlayers()[0]) {
      p1winner.textContent = `${player.name} ${
            winningMsgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
          } ${player.marker}s`;
    } else
      p2winner.textContent = `${player.name} ${
            winningMsgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
          } ${player.marker}s`;
    p1Wins.textContent = `X wins: ${xWins}`;
    p2Wins.textContent = `O wins: ${oWins}`;
  }

  const newGame = document.getElementById("newGame");
  newGame.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;
    p1winner.textContent = "";
    p2winner.textContent = "";
    players.switchActive();
    eraseBoard();
    gameBoard();
    displayBoard();
  });

  function checkForWin() {
    if (
      //row wins
      (board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark()) ||
      // diagonal win left to right descending
      (board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark()) ||
      // diagonal win left to right ascending
      (board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark()) ||
      //column wins
      (board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() === "X" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark())
    ) {
      xWins++;
      p1.classList.remove("alert");
      gameOverMan(players.getActive());
    } else if (
      (board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark()) ||
      // diagonal win left to right descending
      (board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark()) ||
      // diagonal win left to right ascending
      (board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark()) ||
      //column wins
      (board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][0].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][0].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][0].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][1].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][1].getMark() ===
        board.getBoard()[2][1].getMark()) ||
      (board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() === "O" &&
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() === board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[1][2].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark() &&
        board.getBoard()[0][2].getMark() === board.getBoard()[2][2].getMark())
    ) {
      oWins++;
      p2.classList.remove("alert");
      gameOverMan(players.getActive());
    } else players.switchActive();
  }
  return {
    displayBoard
  };
}

gameState();
gameState().displayBoard();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="java.js" defer></script>
<title>Tic Tac (Toe?)</title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="header">
  <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" placeholder="Name" />
    <button type="submit" id="psubmit" class="thisguy">Join the Game</button>
    <button type="button" id="newGame">New Game</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="player1">
    <div id="playerOne">XXX</div>
    <div id="p1name"></div>
    <div id="p1winner">
      <p id="p1announcement"></p>
      <p id="Xwins">X wins: 0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="gameboard"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="player2">
    <div id="playerTwo">OOO</div>
    <div id="p2name"></div>
    <div id="p2winner">
      <p id="p2announcement"></p>
      <p id="Owins">0 wins: 0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've copied your JavaScript and HTML into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/), removing what seemed to be a typo and commenting out the parts of the event handler that tried to use the `players` variable you haven't provided a definition of. It only shows one console.log. Please update the question to provide a [mre]. (Is there, for instance, another event handler you haven't shown?)

Comment: If you're always going to `.preventDefault()` from the "psubmit" click, there's no reason to make it `type=submit`. If you make it `type=button` then there is no default action.

Comment: If you want to add event handler to the `submit` button, then why did you make the button's type `submit` ? Submit buttons are not used like that.
Just make it a normal button and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I've edited in the whole code in there. The other event listeners are for the Cells buttons, and the newGame buttons. I tried editing them both out and it only fires once, I will do some further research into why that is because it doesn't seem to follow what I've read on propagation/bubbling. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: Good luck with it. Re the question, please read through the [mre] link above. The "minimal" part is important, as is the process of getting there. Details in the link. :-)

Comment: @redbreedlove Seems I wasted my time creating a stacksnippet you already dismantled from TJ

Answer (score 0):

```
gameState();
gameState().displayBoard();
```

You call the `gameState()` function twice, thats why you have two event listeners added to your button.

`gameState()` => `playerFactory()` => `submit.addEventListener("click")`
`gameState().displayBoard()` => `playerFactory()` => `submit.addEventListener("click")`